# Time Machine Error -36

Tags: snow-leopard, time-machine, nas

I have a NAS device attached to my router. I'm using it as a backup device for my Mac Book Pro. I'm getting the following error:

> The backup disk image `/Volumes/SHARE-1/MacBookPro.sparsebundle` could not be created (error -36).

I'm not sure what the problem is. The NAS device is a Buffalo external device with a SMB (FAT) format. Could this be the problem?

Comment: Have you upgraded anything on the MBP recently?

Comment: No John, haven't updated anything. Its running Mac OS X version 10.6.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the FAT is the problem. Time Machine [needs an HFS+ formatted drive](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1228127?start=0&tstart=0).

That's quite logical, since files copied from your HFS+ system have many attributes that could not be handled by the FAT filesystem, not even counting the files too long, or the characters that could not be accepted as a valid filename on FAT drives :)

Comment: Thanks MattiSG, is there anyway I can partition the harddrive and format one partition to HFS+  ?

Comment: @Stephen Well, that's another question. If this answer answered your question (_Could [the FAT filesystem] be the problem?_), you should upvote and validate it ;) Then, either simply fire up Disk Utility (in the `Applications/Utilities` folder), or you should ask this question as a new one seeing this is a NAS, and I don't how Disk Utility handles network volumes.

Comment: Thanks for the help Matt, I might post another question. Yes, your right Dick Utility does not support network volumes.

Comment: Time Machine in Mountain Lion defaults to creating a sparse bundle disk image when backing up to ZFS (ZEVO beta). Whilst the question is specific to Snow Leopard, it may be worth reviewing this answer to see whether 10.8 similarly allows a sparse bundle disk image on FAT.